# PHP Warning: oci_execute() [<a href='function.oci-execute'>function.oci-execute</a>]: ORA-01460: unimplemented or unreasonable conversion requested

Tags: php, oracle, oracle-call-interface

> PHP Warning:  oci_execute() [function.oci-execute]: ORA-01460:
>   unimplemented or unreasonable conversion requested in
>   /var/www/html/rest/price/resolve/ResolvePrice.php on line 96

When I pass the hardcoded values $PRODUCT_NUM_ARR and $MEMBER_NAME through an oracle bind variable to execute a stored function, it works fine and I get the result. But when I pass the same values from an array I get the ORA error. I have found difficulty in understanding the ORA error and why it is being caused.

The datatype of the columns PRODUCT_NUM and MEMBER_NAME used in the where clause are as follows and the php variables types are "String" and of length approx 13 characters or less. How do I get rid of this error? I am using Oracle 11.2 , OCI 8, PHP 5.1.6

--MN_CAT_MAP.PRODUCT_NUM                VARCHAR2(100)

--MN_CAT_MAP.MEMBER_ID                  NUMBER(20)

--MN_MEMBER.MEMBER_ID                NOT NULL NUMBER(20)

--MN_MEMBER.MEMBER_NAME              NOT NULL VARCHAR2(100)

```
   public function resolvedPrice($arr_http_data){
   $PRODUCT_NUM_ARR=array('130342','270179'); //this works 
   $MEMBER_NAME='87307-3'; //this works 
   $EFFECTIVE_DATE='2016-12-01';//this works
   //$PRODUCT_NUM_ARR=$arr_http_data['productNumbers']; //This does not work where arr_http_data has an array with same values as the one above which works
   //$MEMBER_NAME=$arr_http_data['customerNumber']; //This does not work where arr_http_data['customerNumber'] has same value as the one above which works
   //$EFFECTIVE_DATE=$arr_http_data['pricingDate']; //does not work
  foreach($PRODUCT_NUM_ARR as $PRODUCT_NUM){
   $sql_proc = "
   DECLARE
            v_MEMBER_ID NUMBER;
            v_PRODUCT_ID NUMBER;
            v_PMLI_PK NUMBER;

   BEGIN
            SELECT cat_map_id INTO v_PRODUCT_ID
            FROM mn_cat_map WHERE product_num = :PRODUCT_NUM and catalog_type = 'INT';

            SELECT member_id INTO v_MEMBER_ID
            FROM mn_member WHERE member_name = :MEMBER_NAME;

            v_PMLI_PK := pkg_name.function_name(:CONFIG_NAME,:BUS_SEG_CODE,v_MEMBER_ID,v_PRODUCT_ID,
                         TO_TIMESTAMP(TO_DATE(:EFFECTIVE_DATE,'YYYY-MM-DD')),
                         TO_TIMESTAMP(TO_DATE(:MODEL_DATE,'YYYY-MM-DD')),
                         :CURRENCY_CODE,:ORG_UNIT_ID,:RESOLVED_PRICE,:RESOLVED_CURRENCY,:COMMITMENT_ID,:RESOLVED_BASE_PRICE,:RESOLVED_DISCOUNT,
                         :RESOLVED_DISCOUNT_TYPE,:RESOLVED_TIER_INDEX,:CONTRACT_ID_NUM,:PRODUCT_GROUP_ID);

   EXCEPTION
        WHEN no_data_found THEN
          dbms_output.put_line('No Prices Found for these data!');
        WHEN others THEN
          dbms_output.put_line('Error!');
   END;
   ";

   $stmt = oci_parse($conn,$sql_proc);
   oci_bind_by_name($stmt,':PRODUCT_NUM',$PRODUCT_NUM,4000,SQLT_CHR);
   oci_bind_by_name($stmt,':MEMBER_NAME',$MEMBER_NAME,4000,SQLT_CHR);
   oci_bind_by_name($stmt,':EFFECTIVE_DATE',$EFFECTIVE_DATE);
   //not sharing the other bind variables that i am passing as it will become too long.

   $result=oci_execute($stmt); //error occurs here when i pass values from the array .this is line 96

   if (!$result){
        $e = oci_error($stmt);  // For oci_execute errors pass the statement handle
        echo 'Caught exception: '.$e."\n";
        print htmlentities($e['message']);
        print "\n<pre>\n";
        print htmlentities($e['sqltext']);
        printf("\n%".($e['offset']+1)."s", "^");
        print  "\n</pre>\n";
        break;
    }
    else {
        $json_response_arr = array("productNumber" => $PRODUCT_NUM,"basePrice" => $RESOLVED_BASE_PRICE,"resolvedPrice" => $RESOLVED_PRICE,"upChargeAmount" => null,"currency" => $RESOLVED_CURRENCY,"pricingDocType" => null,"pricingDocName" => null,"tierName" => "Tier ".$RESOLVED_TIER_INDEX,"errorMessage" => null,"pricingDocId" => $CONTRACT_ID_NUM,"discount" => $RESOLVED_DISCOUNT);

        $resolve_price_arr += array($i => $json_response_arr);

      //  print_r($json_response_arr);
       // echo json_encode($resolve_price_arr,JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
    }
  $i = $i + 1;
}// end for each loop

    $json_response_arr=array("resolvedPrices" => $resolve_price_arr);
    echo json_encode($json_response_arr,JSON_PRETTY_PRINT)."\n\n";
    //print_r($json_response_arr);
    return $json_response_arr;
    echo "</pre>";
    oci_free_statement($stmt);
    oci_close($conn);
}
  else {
      $e = oci_error();
      trigger_error(htmlentities($e['message'], ENT_QUOTES), E_USER_ERROR);
     }
   }// end function resolvePrice()
 }//end Class ResolvePrice

This is the data that i am passing from the Chrome REST Client 
{
   "customerNumber": "111003_CUST",
   "productNumbers": ["1000184", "11100300100"],
   "pricingDate": "2016-12-01",
    "currency": "USD",
    "org": "Root"
}
    // I get the json string from the REST client as follows
    $jsondata = file_get_contents("php://input");
    echo "Raw JSON Data below"."\n".$jsondata;

    // I decode the json into array and pass it to the resolvedPrice
    $json_arr = json_decode($jsondata,true);
    echo "Decoded Json Array is "."\n";
    print_r($json_arr);
```

Comment: Could you try passing one variable using the method that works, and the other variable using the method that doesn't work? I ask this because it could be helpful to know which one of the variables is causing the error (or if both are causing the error).

Comment: Yes,i tried that and only hard coded values work while any value from the array $arr_http_data fails.

Comment: i removed the TO_DATE and TO_TIMESTAMP from the $sql_proc and passed the php converted timestamp and it still wont work and give the same exception. this time i tried to localize this variable and pass the rest of the variables hard coded.

Comment: IN your code the comment suggest PRODUCT_NUM_ARR works, but this is not referenced in the uncommented code, so I assume it doesn't work. Also, how are the PLSQL proc parameters you are calling defined? Are they array types, or scalar?

Comment: You are right, I I have a for each loop which passes each value from $product_num_arr into $product_num variable which is then bound by the oracle bind variable in the oci_bind_by_name function call. Does that make sense ? I didn't paste the complete code but I can definitely do that if it helps to understand.